# FoxPro compiled code output

Tags: vb6, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Trying to do some work on an old FoxPro and VB6 legacy application and I've run into a brick wall.

The VB6 part of the application creates three .qpr file which, I understand, are just SQL queries. It then calls an external .fxp file, which is compiled foxpro code. I am not sure exactly what this is - however, I am assuming it to be a compiled version of an identically-named .prg file in the same folder, which contains the following code:

```
COMPILE "\\Count\Database\Sql_Result.qpr"
WAIT TIMEOUT 1
COMPILE "\\Count\Database\Sql_Total.qpr"
WAIT TIMEOUT 1
COMPILE "\\Count\Database\Sql_Query.qpr"
```

Those are the .qpr files which the VB6 app generates.

When you run this compilation command, it seems to do something. No error is thrown. Yet I can't see it's done very much.

What is the product of the above compile commands, and how can I find it?

Comment: What's in the QPR files?

Comment: COMPILE a QPR file produces a QPX version that contains the compiled code, but it doesn't run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .QPR programs are nothing but a simple .PRG file with renamed extension.  When the main VFP app calls the .qpr program, it just runs the query, the resulting cursor result is created and then VFP does with it whatever it needs to.

If your VFP application is compiled into an EXE, and the original underlying EXE was compiled with .qpr code, then the new versions of .qpr would not be impacted... but not enough to confirm the situation of your app design / implementation.